# Create Directories and Subdirectories as Another User

Tags: permissions, scripting

I am trying to create directories and subdirectories as another user, from inside a shell script.

The problem is, I am running the script as `root`, so the directory is being created with `root` ownership.I have a text file containing the names of directories and subdirectories, and I am using this command to do it:

```
cat dirname.txt | xargs -L 1 mkdir
```

Which looks like this:

```
cet/mnt
cet/mnt/jkl
cet/mnj/lok
```

I tried `sudo` but only the parent directory gets the desired user ownership.

Comment: How did you use `sudo`?

Comment: If you don't know what you're doing, don't do it as root.

Comment: Why do you have to run the script as root? Is that reason really good enough to run as root? (Rule of thumb on Linux is don't run anything as root unless it can't be avoided, in which cases you should normally access root through sudo).

Sudo **can** run commands as any user, not just root, you obviously did not try hard enough. Also, if you managed to successfully create the directories, the only thing you have to do is **chown** to change the ownership. if you want to chown many things at once, you can set a /path/* and voila, all subdirectories and files will have their ownership changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
cat dirName.txt | xargs -L 1 sudo -u ubuntu mkdir -p
```

Comment: it doesn't work permission denied.

Comment: It might be the permission with the directory you are trying to create directories.
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Feb  1 03:36 1
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Feb  1 03:36 3

My file containing name of directories and sub directories.
~# cat dirName.txt
/tmp/1
/tmp/1/2
/tmp/3


The user which you are using to should have permission to create files in the specified directory.

Comment: now parent directories are getting the ownership but the sub directories are with the same root ownership.

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like the following?

```
user="foo"
group="bar"
perm=741

for dir in $(cat dirname.txt); do
    mkdir ${dir}
    chown ${user}:${group} ${dir}
    chmod -R ${perm} ${dir}
done
```

I find it best to utilize variables to make future changes easier. Iterating the directory list instead of a one liner is easier to maintain as well